# Stop Python script with ctrl + c

Tags: python, multithreading, signals

I have a script which uses threads, but it is unable to catch Ctrl + C.

Here it is the sample code to reproduce this error:

```
import threading
import time
import signal

class DummyThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self._running = True
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.stop)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.stop)

    def stop(self, signum=None, frame=None):
        self._running = False

    def run(self):
        while self._running:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("Running")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        t = DummyThread()
        t.start()
        while True:
            print("Main thread running")
            time.sleep(0.5)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("This never gets printed")
        t.stop()
    finally:
        print("Exit")
```

When I run `python3 script.py` it starts running, but it does not catch ctrl+c. I have googled it but I have not found a solution. I have to kill the script with SIGTERM, but I want `DummyThread` to stop gracefully.

Comment: If you add a `print` in `DummyThread.stop`, do you see that?

Comment: And if you remove the two lines where you call `signal.signal`, does it work as expected then?

Comment: That was the problem, now it works, thank. Put it as an answer so I can mark it as accepted

Comment: Why nobody says that OP can not use ```signal.signal ``` in not main Thread?

Comment: @ArtiomKozyrev because that’s not what the problem is here. `signal.signal` is called in `DummyThread.__init__`, which *is* called in the main thread.

Comment: @mkrieger1 hereby OP can not use ```signal``` to communicate directly with another ```Thread```, it is what the documentation say and recommends to use sync primitives. The problem is inappropriate use of ```signal``` in the code, though program can work without use of signal library, and even without sync primitives, ```daemon Thread``` is fine to do all steps which were required for the program by OP.

Comment: But the signal is not used to communicate *directly* with another thread. It is only used to call a method which sets a variable to `False`. *Then* the thread reacts to this changed variable by polling it. (Your answer is correct nevertheless, though, btw.)

Comment: @mkrieger1 anyway we have to handle ```KeyboardInterrupt```  and in the handling of this exception we have to ping ```DummyThread```, so my point is that we do not need ```signal``` to do it.

Comment: Yes we do not need it. But we *could* use it, and not handle `KeyboardInterrupt` instead. We just need to choose *one or the other*, but *not both*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> class DummyThread(threading.Thread):
>
>     def __init__(self):
>         threading.Thread.__init__(self)
>         self._running = True
>         signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.stop)
>         signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.stop)
> ```

The program actually does not work as expected *because* of those last two lines and would work *without* them.

The reason is that, if you press <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>, the `SIGINT` signal is handled by the signal handler that is set up by `signal.signal` and `self.stop` is called. So the thread should actually stop.

But in the *main* thread, the `while True` loop is still running. Since the signal has already been handled, there will be **no `KeyboardInterrupt` exception raised** by the Python runtime. Therefore you never get to the `except` part.

> ```
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>     try:
>         t = DummyThread()
>         t.start()
>         while True:            # you are stuck in this loop
>             print("Main thread running")
>             time.sleep(0.5)
>     except KeyboardInterrupt:  # this never happens
>         print("This never gets printed")
>         t.stop()
> ```

Only one signal handler should be set up to call the `stop` method. So there are two options to solve the problem:

1. Handle the signal implicitly by catching the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception. This is achieved by simply removing the two `signal.signal(...)` lines.
2. Set up an explicit signal handler (as you did by using `signal.signal` in `DummyThread.__init__`), but remove the `while True:` loop from the main thread and do not try to handle `KeyboardInterrupt`. Instead, just wait for the `DummyThread` to finish on its own by using its `join` method:

   ```
   if __name__ == "__main__":
       t = DummyThread()
       t.start()
       t.join()
       print("Exit")
   ```

Answer (score 2):

The main point is that you can't work with signals in any other Thread except the Main Thread. The Main Thread is the only one which can receive signals and handle them. I can offer the following solution, it is based on `Event` sync primitive.

[According to Python documantation:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html)

> Signals and threads
>   Python signal handlers are always executed in the main Python thread, even if the signal was received in another thread. This means that signals can’t be used as a means of inter-thread communication. You can use the synchronization primitives from the threading module instead.

Besides, only the main thread is allowed to set a new signal handler.

```
from threading import Thread, Event
import time


class DummyThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self, event: Event):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stop_event = event

    def run(self):
        # we are monitoring the event in the Main Thread
        while not self.stop_event.is_set():  
            time.sleep(1)
            print("Running")
        # only Main Thread can make the point reachable
        print("I am done !")  


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        e = Event() 
        t = DummyThread(e)
        t.start()
        while True:
            print("Main thread running")
            time.sleep(0.5)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        e.set()
    finally:
        print("Exit")
```

Another possible choice is to use `daemon` Thread for such tasks like in your code example (when you just printing smth in the screen every second, rather than e.g. close database connection or some similar task). If main thread is stoped the `daemon` Thread will stop too.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in your code, you used `KeyboardInterrupt` to call `stop()` function. See how Listener does the same task and stops the execution which was unable to catch from *Ctrl + C*. You dont have to  kill the script with *SIGTERM* anymore

```
import threading
import time
import signal
import os
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

class DummyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self._running = True
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.stop)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.stop)

    def stop(self, signum=None, frame=None):
        self._running = False
        print ("Bye Bye . .")
        os._exit(1)

    def run(self):
        while self._running:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("Running")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = DummyThread()
    def func2():
        try:
            t.start()
            while True:
                print("Main thread running")
                time.sleep(0.5)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("No need for this")
            t.stop()
        finally:
            print("Exit")

    def func1():
        with Listener(on_press = t.stop) as listener :
            listener.join()

    threading.Thread(target=func1).start()
    threading.Thread(target=func2).start()
```

Comment: But I need to use SIGINT, it's a script running in background

Comment: @AlejoDev you can not handle signal in not the main thread, and use signal for communication betwenn Threads.